# how can I debug git's sneaky merge?

Tags: git

I have a `~/.gitconfig` file with

```
[branch]
    autosetuprebase = always
```

and it works fine for a very long time, last checked on git-2.28.0 and git-2.28.0.windows.1

But, when using the same file (copied over) with `git-2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`, as soon as i run `git pull` it will open my text editor with a Merge message (which sometimes get's me offguard and i end up just exiting the editor, which completes the dammed merge). If i test the setting on the working copy, it shows the expected value:

```
$ git config branch.autosetuprebase
always
```

Clearly something is not working on my setup, or is broken with that particular git version. How do I go about debugging where the problem is at? My goal is to never, ever, see an automatic merge commit suggestion unles I actively ask for `git merge`.

Comment: are you saying you copied a gitconfig from windows to a mac? I would expect a text file from windows to have different line endings than mac's are used to.

Comment: both line endings would work on `.gitconfig` (specially as i run posix git on windows using a msys base), but that's irrelevant, just mentioned that it happens with one version compiled for one platform, and that i took the time to test the same version in other platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to figure out what's going on, I'd first check that `git config -l` provides the values that you expect.  For example, someone may have also set `branch.autosetupmerge`, or some other option may be interfering.

If you're not sure if a config option is interfering, try setting `HOME` to some other directory and create a `.gitconfig` file with just that option within that directory.  You can then modify that `.gitconfig` as you debug to see if it's interfering.

Then, I'd create a new branch with `git branch` that tracks another branch and then dump the output again with `git config -l` to make sure that the tracking branch has the appropriate `branch.<name>.rebase` setting.  If it doesn't, then you know that there's a problem, and using the custom `.gitconfig` can be helpful to find the culprit.

You may also want to try with Homebrew's Git.  Apple applies patches to their Git and it's possible that it's broken in some way.  That version should support the option, since it was added in 2.20, but it's possible that it may be broken in that particular version.

Comment: didn't know about `config -l`... always typed each setting :) but it's the same as the output i placed above. I do not think it is the setting alone. ...but you might have solved the problem. I thought i was always using brew's git, but maybe i used apple's at some point and that is buggy?